# Starting Activity with a Floatingbutton

Tags: android, button, floating-action-button, start-activity

So I have my List class which has a floatingbutton. I want to make it so that when i click that button it goes into another one of my activities, MainActivity. This is the code I have for my list class.

```
public class List extends Activity {
ImageButton floatButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    populateUsersList();

    floatButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    floatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent barcodes = new Intent (List.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(barcodes);
        }
    });
}

private void populateUsersList() {
    // Construct the data source
    ArrayList<User> arrayOfUsers = User.getUsers();
    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers);
    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

It seems like it should work, but every time i click the button, this error code pops up.

```
06-15 11:34:46.299 2971-2971/com.example.pethoalpar.zxingexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.pethoalpar.zxingexample, PID: 2971
                                                                               android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.pethoalpar.zxingexample/apn.keychains.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
                                                                                   at apn.keychains.List$1.onClick(List.java:28)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your activity at the manifest file.

Add this to your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

All your `<activity... />` tags should be placed under the `<application.. />` tag.

Comment: @user2543577 You might want to upvote the answer as well as accept it.